# Logging JMX MBean access into a log file

Tags: java, security, jmx

Is there any way that I can track the connections made to my application's JMX Mbeans? Though the JMX access is password protected but strict information security guidelines are forcing us to track the info related to who peaked into the system even using JMX.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to implement your own [MBeanServerForwarder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/remote/MBeanServerForwarder.html) and do the logging there. I use a similar approach for access control (beyond the out-of-the-box solution).

Comment: Though am yet to try my custom implementation of MBeanServerForwarder, I was wondering, how do you get hold of the Request object and the Parameters? Without getting the request info, am afraid I'll not be able to log anything meaningful.

Comment: Well, all calls to the MBeanServer goes through the MBSF (you need to delegate to the underlying MBeanServer in your implementation) so you should have all the information you need - when retrieving an attribute from an MBean for example the getAttribute(ObjectName name, String attribute) method gets called and returns an object - you can easily log which attribute of which MBean was accessed (including the return value).